# calling controller method using jquery but method not redirecting to its corresponding view

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a page "`GetData.cshtml`" where I need to fill up some textbox data and send to the controller method. I am using jquery to send data to the controller method.

```
//GetData.cshtml
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#btn_sbmt_recommendation').click(function () {            
        $.post("/RegistrationModels/Registration_card",
        {
            firm_id: $('#id_reg_id').val(), 
            amount: $('#id_amount').val()
            });
        console.log("job done....");
    });
})
```

While debugging the app, the controller method is called successfully.

```
public ActionResult Registration_card(string reg_id, string amount)
        {
            try
            {
                // code block
                return View(updated_firm);
            }
            catch (Exception ex) { throw; }
        }
```

As my requirement, I want to display the data in `Registration_card.cshtml` page, but it is not redirecting to the page.
The console message `console.log("job done....");` in the jquery block is showing. It means the page is again back to `GetData.cshtml`. Is it due to using jquery to call controller method?
How can I go to page `Registration_card.cshtml` after calling the controller method `Registration_card` via jquery.

I also tried with the below code, but it is also not working.

```
public ActionResult Registration_card(string firm_id, string ward_calani_num, string amount)
        {
            try
            {
                // code block
                return RedirectToAction("Registration_card", updated_firm);
            }
            catch (Exception ex) { throw; }
        }
```

Comment: This is how AJAX works. It ignores server side redirects. If you want to redirect the page, then the AJAX request itself becomes almost irrelevant.

Comment: `console.log("job done....");` is *outside* the jquery call, so has no relevance to whether it worked on not (remove the $.ajax call and the console.log will still fire)

Comment: I would remove the almost from almost irrelevant here :)

Comment: `RedirectToAction` returns a 302 with the new url.  The browser handles this "normally" - by getting the 302 response then making a *second* call to the provided url.  You only have the first call, so in your post callback / error handler you need to check for a 302 then redirect the page in your code (as the browser does when entering the url in the address bar) - *if* that's the way you want to handle it (the alternative as alluded to above is to just let the form submit).   It won't be automatic

Comment: You'll handle that in the ajax call's "callback" method...  (your controller returns its data to the callback.. since that is what called the method...)  It's easier to just serialize the whole form, so something like " formresult = $('#'+formID).serialize(); $.post("/RegistrationModels/Registration_card", formresult, function(data){... do what you want with data here... or maybe just set the browser's location using location.assign(myurl.com)....});...  So the 3rd parameter there is the callback which is an anonymous function that executes once the method returns something.

Comment: https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/#jQuery-post-url-data-success-dataType  If you need to get back some parameters to be used in the redirection, it's convenient to use JSON... if you do that, set the return type of the controller method to Task<JsonResult>... so public Task<JsonResult> Registration_card...

Comment: @pcalkins can you post the solution, it will be more helpful. thank you!!!

Comment: it's difficult to know what behavior you want here... in general you'd make an ajax call to avoid a full page load... so you'd update the parts of the DOM that you need to update.  That might even be getting back HTML from the controller and populating a part of the DOM with that.  It depends on your requirements and why you're making an ajax call (as opposed to a standard form post) to begin with.

Answer (score 2):

According to your question, it seems you want to redirect/go to the `Registration_card.cshtm` from `GetData.cshtml` by taking some data from the `GetData.cshtml` to the `Registration_card` `ActionMethod` which will actually show the `Registration_card.cshtm`.

If the above scenario is true, then you do not need to Ajax Post request as your `ActionMethod` is `HttpGet` as you do not specify it is as `HttpPost`. So the workaround can be something like the below code.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#btn_sbmt_recommendation').click(function () {
        var id_reg_id=$('#id_reg_id').val();   
        var id_amount=$('#id_amount').val();         
        location.href=`/RegistrationModels/Registration_card?reg_id=${id_reg_id}&amount=${id_amount}`;
      
        //$.post("/RegistrationModels/Registration_card",
           //    {
           //        firm_id: $('#id_reg_id').val(),
           //        amount: $('#id_amount').val()
           //    });
          //console.log("job done....");
    });
})
```

Answer (score -1):

If want to redirect page you should use javascript or jquery because when you use jquery then controller not working for redirect.

Comment: What do you want to say, should use jQuery/JavaScript or not use????

Comment: Yes, if you want to redirect then use  jQuery/JavaScript.